# Perl: How to declare and implement function `say`

Tags: perl, implementation, declaration

Simple question:

I want to write a function like `say`.

But it had one bad feature: a filehandle.

```
       say FILEHANDLE LIST
       say FILEHANDLE
       say LIST
       say
```

How to declare it? Is it possible?

P.S: 
I find an example with `myopen(*;$)`, but it's not the same thing.
P.P.S:
I need this function in old Perl versions, because it is annoying to write `print "\n"`

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, `say` on a filehandle is actually an indirect method. Anything that you can dream up will need a comma.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Perl6::Say](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aSay) does just that.

It cleverly emulates the `say FILEHANDLE TEXT` syntax by taking advantage of Perl's usually very annoying [indirect method call syntax](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html).  It loads [IO::Handle](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aHandle) turning every filehandle into an object and creates `IO::Handle->say`.  Now `say FILEHANDLE TEXT` is actually `FILEHANDLE->say(TEXT)`.

It does have caveats.  From [the docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aSay#General)...

```
Use it just like print (except that it only supports the indirect
object syntax when the stream is a bareword). That is, assuming
the relevant filehandles are open for output, you can use any of these:

say @data;
say FH @data;
FH->say(@data);
*FH->say(@data);
(\*FH)->say(@data);
say $fh, @data;
$fh->say(@data);

but not any of these:

say {FH} @data;
say {*FH} @data;
say {\*FH} @data;
say $fh @data;
say {$fh} @data;
```

**UPDATE**: To make this even simpler, I have just uploaded [Say::Compat](https://metacpan.org/module/MSCHWERN/Say-Compat-0.01/lib/Say/Compat.pm) which loads either Perl6::Say or `use feature 'say'` depending on your version of Perl.

That's the best you're likely to get without playing with [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aDeclare).

Comment: @loldop I've made the process even simpler but writing Say::Compat.  See the edit to the post for details.

Comment: Notes: 1) `say $fh @data;` should work just as well as `say FH @data`, despite the docs saying otherwise. 2) `say $fh, @data;` doesn't work as it should (but that's not really a problem). 3) That trick gives the wrong result for `my $_ = "abc"; say;`.

Comment: @ikegami You have mistaken this answer for the [Perl6::Say bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Perl6-Say). ;)

Comment: Maybe the first, but the second and third notes have nothing to do with Perl6::Say. They are unmentioned limits of your suggestion to use indirect obj notation.

Comment: @ikegami Those limits I posted are copied from [the Perl6::Say docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6::Say#General). It would be nice if you sent them the additional limitations you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

`say` cannot be recreated by subs.

```
>perl -E"say prototype('CORE::say') // 'Special'"
Special
```

You'd need a call parser and call checker to achieve that. See [Syntax::Feature::Loop](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Syntax%3a%3aFeature%3a%3aLoop) for an example.

Comment: hm, which version of perl? also i want to write function _like_ `say`

Comment: In any version of Perl. Or you mean call parser/checker? Unfortunately, 5.14 for the complete functionality, although 5.12 has a "lite" version. There are cruder tools usable in older versions (Devel::Declare?, keyword plugin, ...?), but I'm not that familiar with them.